# Understanding relationship between typescript modules and declaration files

Tags: typescript

I have just written my first node package in typescript. it has 6 modules with several hundred lines of code each. To get the tests passing, I have put declarations at the top of each module; they are included as needed in other modules (along with everything else).

Now I need to make it consumable by other typescript modules -- so I need to create an "index.d.ts" file.

I am wondering if the best way to structure it is to have that file include others? So, for instance, if I have modules `foo.ts` and `bar.ts` should I create `foo.d.ts` and `bar.d.ts` and then include them in `index.d.ts`? (Should I be thinking of them like ".h" files in c?)

Also, how to get the definitions back to the modules? Should `foo.ts` import from `foo.d.ts`? When `bar.ts` imports from `foo`, is it getting the merged version of `bar.ts` and `bar.d.ts`? Even if they all import from `index.d.ts`, how is this differentiated from importing from `index.ts`?

An explanation of how import interacts with modules and declarations of the same name would be very helpful.

Comment: You have asked seven or so questions here. As someone who might be able to help, I would find it useful for you to differentiate (a) the single question that you would really like to have answered from (b) the considerations you are making that happen to be in the form of questions. That would make it easier for me to provide an answer that is relevant to (a).

Answer (score 0):

As @ShaunLuttin points out I ask a lot of questions here. The key word in the the title to my question was "understanding" -- I was misunderstanding the relation of "d.ts" and "ts" files, but I think I've clarified it.

The key step was adding `"declarations": true` to my `tsconfig.json` file. This resulted in the declaration files for all my modules being automatically generated and put in `dist/` alongside the `.js` files. My takeaway, to put it stoichiometrically:

```
foo.ts <=> foo.d.ts + foo.js + foo.js.map
```

In other words, I was just confusing myself by thinking of moving interfaces into ".d.ts" files *in my source directory*. The typescript source within a package is self-sufficient; whether to factor out interfaces into other typescript files (not declaration files) in source is an orthogonal concern.

The declaration files are meant as the type component to complement the javascript code that travels across package boundaries. (In theory one should even be able to go backward from "d.ts" + ".js" files to a ".ts" file; @S.Klechkovski points out that the source map file contains relevant information [thanks!] ... I still don't think there is a tool to put the three together though.) The typescript files remain the "single point of authority" so as to satisfy "don't repeat yourself".

[NB I'll leave my answer unaccepted for a few days in case someone can give a clearer explanation.]

Comment: *.d.ts files contain just the type declarations for the corresponding *.ts file. The declaration files are used by the TypeScript compiler just for the type checking. The compiler can also produce source maps ("soureMap": true). The source map can be used to map the compiled code back to TypeScript.
foo.js + foo.js.map <=> foo.ts